# WinForms and Access Database Attachments

Tags: winforms, ms-access-2007

If I have a PDF file saved into an attachment field in an Access database, is there anyway I could get that attachment from the database and view it in the WinForm? Or the WinForm WebBrowser maybe?

Or am I just better off sticking to a field in the database that tells me the file path of said file so I can navigate my WebBrowser to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with Access since long before Access 2007 introduced the Attachments field type, so I have a history of shying away from imbedding images and documents in the database. (They tended to bloat the database quite significantly, and the OLE "wrappers" added to the files were a real nuisance when trying to extract the files via code.)

Access 2007+ makes this quite a bit simpler with the Attachments field because DAO has been updated to support `.SaveToFile` and `.LoadFromFile` on Attachments. Also, attachments are (apparently) compressed when saved to the database, which should help with the bloat problem.

So, I'd say that the choice is really up to you, because if you want to view (or preview, or open) the PDF attachment in your WinForm then you'll probably wind up using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` to save the attachment as a temporary file anyway. Therefore, whatever mechanism you use to preview/view/open the attachment will be working on a file; it will either be

- a temporary file extracted from the database, or
- a persistent file in a filesystem that you reference from a pathname or URL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file from the database you would need to read the bytes from the database and write them to a new pdf file, then point your viewer to that file.  To view a pdf directly on the WinForm you would need a 3rd party control.  If you have a plugin where you can view pdfs in your browser, the WinForm WebBrowser will work.

Storing just the path in the database leads to less hassle from a coding standpoint, because you are going to have to point your viewer to a file anyway.  Also is theres an issue with the database, there is a higher chance all the attachments will be lost.  On the flipside, if just the paths are stored you need to make sure those paths are always accessible.

I would recommend storing them outside of the database for the above reasons, especially if this is a larger database.